# What is the analog of Matlab options=optimset('display','off') and f = fzero(....) in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to write in python this code. But can't find any analogs (similar functions)
Is there any possibility to write this code in Python? Thanks.
Matlab

```
function y = a(x1,x2,y1,y2,p,c)    
y = x1 - x2 - (y1 - y2 - p/c * (exp(-c*y2) - exp(-c*y1)) + p/c *(exp(-c*x2) - exp(-c*x1))); 
end

for i = 1:size(c,1):
    for j = i:-1:1:
        if j == i:
            x2(j,i) = 0; 
        else 
            x2(j,i) = x1(j+1,i);
        end
    options=optimset('display','off');
    ff = fzero('a',x1(j,i), options, x2(j,i), zb(j), zt(j), surpor(j),c(j));
    x1(j,i) = ff;
    end
end
```

I tryed in Python:
Python

```
def a(x1,x2,y1,y2,p,c):      
    y = x1 - x2 - (y1 - y2 - p/c * (np.exp(-c*y2) - np.exp(-c*y1)) + p/c *(np.exp(-c*x2) - np.exp(-c*x1)))
    return y

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(i, 1, -1):
        if j == i:
            x2[j, i] = 0
        else:
            x2[j, i] = x1[j+1, i]
            y = a(x1[j,i], x2[j,i], zb[j], zt[j], surpor[j], c[j])
        yy = fsolve(y, x0=0)
        x1[j, i] = yy
```

### But got mistake:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12792/963369087.py in

```
  9         # y = Y2 - Y1 - (y2 - y1 - phi/c * (np.exp(-c*y1) - np.exp(-c*y2)) + phi/c *(np.exp(-c*Y1) - np.exp(-c*Y2)))
 10         y = a(x1[j,i], x2[j,i], zb[j], zt[j], surpor[j], c[j])

---> 11         yy = fsolve(y, x0=0)
 12         x1[j, i] = yy
 13 print(y)
```

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)

```
158                'diag': diag}
159 
--> 160     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
161     if full_output:
162         x = res['x']
```

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)

```
224     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
225         args = (args,)
--> 226     shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
227     if epsfcn is None:
228         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps
```

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)

```
 22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
 23                 output_shape=None):
 ---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
 25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
 26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):
```

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Comment: Did you by any chance use `a`, `range` or `fsolve` as variable names?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error with stack trace. You give us a fraction of the information about the error that you have.

Comment: mapf, no, I didn't use these a, range, fsolve as variable names...

Comment: What are your function inputs? Please provide a minimum executable code.